# Regexp engine misbehaves in Atom

Tags: regex, utf-8, atom-editor

I'm trying to remove all lines starting with whitespace characters from a big text file using Atom. The regular expression I use is `^[\s]+.*$`. The problem is, it selects not only lines starting with whitespace, but also one line after them. The file is in UTF-8 and most characters are Cyrillic. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Goal: remove any line that begins with whitespace, including the newline on the end.
- Pattern to use: `^\n|(^[ \t]+.*\n*)`
- Remark: `[\s]` will match any whitespace. Whereas `[ \t]` will match spaces and tabs.

Comment: This matches only non-empty lines. However, empty lines can later be removed with `^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+`. The problem is solved.

Comment: Ok, this should do it all: `^\n|(^[ \t]+.*\n*)`